# Utilizing fancybox, jquery-isotope, and truncated text, all in one! (Oh, and it's in Drupal, too)

Tags: jquery, drupal, fancybox, jquery-isotope, truncate

We are using Drupal for one of the sites we maintain (and JQuery as the library). One of our pages is using the jquery-isotope plugin (specially the views-isotope module) for sorting in views, and fancybox to display the contents of the body field in full. This is because, as it stands, most of the content of the body is hidden by a css height and an overflow:hidden.

As you can imagine, such a crude method doesn't really look pretty. Much of the text is cut off, leaving spare serifs and whatnot to make it look particularly "dirty". The next step in this, then, was to truncate the text and append a "..." so that text wouldn't get cut off.

However, fancybox pulls the content AS IS into the overlay. So when you truncate the text of the body, it truncates in the overlay, too.

Basically, my question is, is there a way to truncate the text until the click that opens fancybox occurs? How would I send the full content to fancybox without losing the truncation when I click? When I started a jsfiddle to work on this, I didn't incorporate either isotope or fancybox into my calculations: I just built it out with a substring, cloned the original content, and then replaced the substring on click. But that, as you can imagine, breaks the page, because there is nothing to tell it ONLY to do this in relation to fancybox, and not just on random. Nor do I know how to resume the truncation of the text when fancybox closes.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwEeq/22/).

Here is the html:

```
<div class="element">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
            nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut
            wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
            lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure
            dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum
            dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio
            dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore
            te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.item {
width:300px !important;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden; }
```

Here is the script:

```
var originalState = $(".element").clone().text();

$(".item").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().length > 30) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 27));
        $(this).append('...');
    }
});

$(".element").click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(originalState);
});
```

How would I go about tying this in with fancybox, so that the text is trimmed until you click, fancybox gets the full text, and then on close, things are returned to the trimmed style of before?

Note: If I've made any fatal errors with my code, please let me know. I am young in the ways of JavaScript and JQuery, but trying extremely hard to learn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were already half way.

Since you already cloned the original text :

```
var originalState = $(".element").clone().text();
```

... the only thing you have to do is to use it as the content of fancybox, so instead of this :

```
$(".element").click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(originalState);
});
```

... do this :

```
$(".element").click(function () {
    $.fancybox(originalState);
});
```

See **[forked JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2RefS/)**

That will display the cloned text in fancybox and leave intact your trimmed text.

**EDIT** (Feb 28, 2013) :

If you are cloning more than one item, then you could tweak your code to arrange them in an array and bind fancybox to each item separately like :

```
var originalState = new Array();
$(".item").each(function (i) {
    originalState[i] = $(this).clone().text();
    if ($(this).text().length > 30) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 27)).append('...');
    }
    $(this).click(function () {
        $.fancybox(originalState[i]);
    });
});
```

See new **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vcxDh/1/)**

Comment: That was perfect. We stumbled onto another issue with cloning (ie cloning more than just the first instance of fancybox and keeping them tied with their respective divs), but this very much answered my initial question. Thanks!

Comment: @Kaylsbeth : see my edited answer for cloning multiple items.

Comment: I wish I had enough rep to upvote you, @JFK. Seriously. That worked like a charm. And, I learned something new and fantastic to do with arrays! Excellent!